# Have problem with Fade in and Fade out effect using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I create the Fade in and Fade out effect in our WordPress website using these codes...
it's good, but I need them one at a time, the way you have it is all at once? I mean I want each bullet point to appear at once but by all bullet points together.

I want individual bullet points one at a time, Right now I have them showing up all at once - which is what we don’t want

You also can see it on my website I appley these code at three sections on site: http://imalreadyhere.info/network1
But now I need them one at a time, the way you have it is all at once?

Please Help - Thank You

```css
.fade-in {
      animation: fadeIn 2s infinite alternate ease;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="fade-in">
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1......  2......  3..... Not: 1 2 3

Comment: I want each bullet point to appear at once but by all bullet points together. I update my code please check again.

Comment: I want individual bullet points one at a time, Right now I have them showing up all at once - which is what we don’t want

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is known as a typewriter effect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This shows the basic use of a typewriter effect.

Comment: I want each bullet point to appear at once but by all bullet points together. I update my code please check again.

Comment: I want individual bullet points one at a time, Right now I have them showing up all at once - which is what we don’t want